# How to find tts.SythensizetoFile has been completed in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How to find tts.sythensize to file is over?? I just want to display a toast  that tts.sythensize is over, Once it has been completed.How to do that?

Whether there are any specific ways to find tts processing has been finished?

```
 HashMap<String,String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
 String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
 String destFileName = "/sdcard/sdsd.wav";
 myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, question);
 tts.synthesizeToFile(question1, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [utterance listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener%28android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener%29) should work with synthesizeToFile as well:

```
tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener( /* ... */ );
```

Note that for the listener to work, you NEED (!) to have an utterance id (as you do) and the listener needs to be registered before invoking synthesizeToFile.